# Workaround of Misleading error "The configuration of your org has changed, please reload the page. Missing dependent object: SObject: Settings__Feed"?

Tags: feeditem, gack, feedcomment

Back in September the 23th 2021 I have opened a case in Salesforce Support about the issue on our project "The configuration of your org has changed, please reload the page. Missing dependent object: SObject: Settings__Feed".

I am building a dynamic user interface to traverse fields and relationships and I have faced a strange error on one particular case.

When I have `Settings__c` setting included in a package and also deleted custom setting with the same name in the org, when the following code is executed within the package

```
List<String> toReturn = new List<String>();
for (SObjectType t: FeedComment.FeedItemId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()) {
toReturn.add(t.getDescribe().getName());
}
return toReturn;
```

it fails with a strange error

```
The configuration of your org has changed, please reload the page. Missing dependent object: SObject: Settings__Feed
```

which I cannot catch and log.

This is very strange, since this error doesn't happen when I execute the same code on subscriber org outside of the package.

By reverse engineering and black box testing, I have found out that this error is somehow related to `FeedComment.FeedItemId` field and the presence of duplicate unpackaged custom settings, but I still don't understand why this error happens and what does it mean?

Despite of the suggestion to reload the page, page reload never helps to resolve this.

Also when I try to `ERASE` the unpackaged custom settings `Settings__c`, I see another error.

```
An internal server error has occurred
An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!

Error ID: 61453672-514299 (902272532)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I have received a feedback that they have opened a Known Issue https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002Zl10QAC

The workaround is the erase the unpackaged custom settings `Settings__c`

Comment: So how is this "erase" different from the one that produced the "internal server error" - or is this an error that one can swallow, because the erasure is successful nevertheless?

Comment: Salesforce didn't provide any feedback on internal error. I had some dependencies which I was able to resolve and avoid that internal error. It is important that now we have a public known issue link which we can subscribe and monitor.